# bootstrap date picker reverse days of the week

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

is there a way to reverse the bootstrap date picker days of the week

at my database there is a working days of the week lets say [0, 1]; it means you can book this item only at Sunday and Monday

at bootstrap date picker script i can do

```
daysOfWeekDisabled: "0, 1"
```

but that will make those days disabled which is not what i want those must be the only enabled days, the question is how i can revers those number? to show me

```
daysOfWeekDisabled:"2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you are asking, but I think what you have as the reverse days of the week is correct.  Assuming that your datepicker is [eternicode](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/) version, your HTML would look like:

```
<input class="form-control" data-provide="datepicker" name="theDate" id="theDate" required="required" aria-required="true" />
```

and your JS would look like:

```
$("#theDate").datepicker({
   daysOfWeekDisabled: "2, 3, 4, 5, 6"
});
```

One thing you will want to keep in mind, though, is that someone could always manually type in a date that was on a day other than Sunday or Monday.

Hope this helps.